# npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function while doing > npm install @angular/cli@latest

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting this error "npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function" in windows
while doing:

```
> npm install
```

I have also tried with:

```
> npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

And the error is the same, this is the file.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli@latest'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@5.0.3
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose npm-session f3412af9e2e7111f
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 verbose stack TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
7 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:287:18
7 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:184:5)
8 verbose cwd E:\...
9 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
10 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@angular/cli@latest"
11 verbose node v14.15.1
12 verbose npm  v5.0.3
13 error cb.apply is not a function
14 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see, that the problem derives from your current `npm` package.

```
7 verbose stack TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
7 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:287:18
```

Your version of npm is pretty old.

```
2 info using npm@5.0.3
```

We're currently at 7.9.0.
Please run

```
npm install -g npm@7.9.0
```

and then try to install angular cli again. This will surely do the trick.